# How to transpose a column and make it a header in R

Tags: r, dplyr

How do I reorganize the data with the first column as the header?  In the *iris* data set, for example, I would like the three different species types to appear as headers. I see why the following doesn't work, but I am not sure of a better way to do it.

```
iris
iris<-iris%>%relocate(Species,.before = Sepal.Length)
iris
names(iris)<-iris%>%distinct(Species)
iris<-iris[,-1]
head(iris)
```

I have seen how to do it when the column that I want to make into a header contains only unique values.

I have also tried `melt()`, but I am not clear on how to use it, and the R documentation was not extremely useful.

```
melt(t(iris),"Species")
```

Comment: What's the output you're trying to get exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `names` assignment is not correct as the `distinct` on 'Species' returns a `data.frame/tibble` with one column whereas `names` expect it to be a vector.  Second issue is that there are 5 columns in 'iris' and assigning 3 'Species' results in imbalance of length.  Here, we may need to reshape

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
data(iris)
iris %>%
     mutate(rn = rowid(Species)) %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from = Species, values_from =1:4 )
```

Comment: Yes, ```pivot_wider()``` does the trick.  Thank you!

Comment: I used that solution on a simpler/smaller data set and it worked great.

```
l<-data.frame(Year=rep("2021",20),
           Increment=sample(rep(c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"),5)),
           jobID=sample(rep(c("F124","F675","F984","F335","F178"),4)))
```
```
l%>%mutate(rn=rowid(Increment))%>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Increment,values_from = jobID)
```

Is there any way to align the jobID's in the rows such that if there is not a jobID for a specific Increment, it will just be blank or show "NA"?

Comment: Not sure why ``` tick marks``` are working to indicate code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
iris %>% cbind(sapply(levels(.$Species), `==`, .$Species))
```

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species setosa versicolor virginica
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <lgl>  <lgl>      <lgl>    
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa  TRUE   FALSE      FALSE    
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa  TRUE   FALSE      FALSE    
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa  TRUE   FALSE      FALSE    
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa  TRUE   FALSE      FALSE    
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa  TRUE   FALSE      FALSE    
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa  TRUE   FALSE      FALSE    
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa  TRUE   FALSE      FALSE    
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa  TRUE   FALSE      FALSE    
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa  TRUE   FALSE      FALSE    
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa  TRUE   FALSE      FALSE    
# ... with 140 more rows
```